# Android Studio - Changing day/night theme and language locale in one "recreate()"?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, theme-daynight

I'm having a very strange issue where if I change the language and recreate it will switch the day/night back to system default, and when I change the day/night it will change the language back to the system default. So, if I put these functions in the OnCreate event, it will be an endless loop. If I use the functions separately, they work as intended. But I can't change both.

This is how I change the language:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) public void SetLanguage()
{
Locale locale = new Locale("zh");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
configuration.setLocale(locale);
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
recreate();
}
```

This is how I change the day/night settings:

```
public void SetTheme(){
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
}
//This method automatically recreates the activity, even if I don't have it specified
```

They are both placed `OnCreate`, I already tried placing them before and after `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` but the result is the same. Basically what's happening, is an endless loop where they are both affecting each other. Language changes the dark theme the back to light on recreate, and dark theme changes the language back to English when it recreates. So it happens forever. Is there a way to simultaneously change both and recreate only once? Thank you!

EDIT: Also, I have tried removing the `recreate()` after setting the language. But then if the theme is already dark in the system settings, then it won't recreate and the language change won't appear. That's not an ideal solution. I hope there's a way to change both and `recreate()` only once. Or if there's another more proper way to deal with this. Because many apps have this functionality. Thank you, again!

Comment: You're creating an empty `Configuration`, try copying the existing one instead to avoid losing the dark theme setting. I'm guessing `AppCompatDelegate` does the same under the hood, which is why you lose the language. I suggest not using `AppCompatDelegate` but using `Configuration.setUiMode` instead.

Comment: @Nicolas How can I use ```Configuration.setUiMode```, it keeps coming up with an error, can you please give me an example string how I would use that to change the theme? Thank you.

Comment: I don't know, I never used it. I was just giving a hint on where to start.